# Make a typeclass instance automatically an instance of another

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances

What I'd like to achieve is that any instance of the following class (`SampleSpace`) should automatically be an instance of `Show`, because `SampleSpace` contains the whole interface necessary to create a String representation and hence all possible instances of the class would be virtually identical.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Ratio (Rational)                                               

class SampleSpace space where                                               
    events          :: Ord a => space a -> [a]                              
    member          :: Ord a => a -> space a -> Bool                        
    probability     :: Ord a => a -> space a -> Rational                    

instance (Ord a, Show a, SampleSpace s) => Show (s a) where                 
    show s = showLines $ events s                                           
        where                                                               
        showLines [] = ""                                                   
        showLines (e:es) = show e ++ ":   " ++ (show $ probability e s)
                                  ++ "\n" ++ showLines es
```

Since, as I found out already, while matching instance declarations GHC only looks at the head, and not at contraints, and so it believes `Show (s a)` is about Rational as well:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Helpers.Probability ( Helpers/Probability.hs, interpreted )

Helpers/Probability.hs:21:49:
    Overlapping instances for Show Rational
      arising from a use of ‘show’
    Matching instances:
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance (Ord a, Show a, SampleSpace s) => Show (s a)
        -- Defined at Helpers/Probability.hs:17:10
    In the expression: show
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(show $ probability e s)’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘(show $ probability e s) ++ "" ++ showLines es
```

Question: is it possible (otherwise than by enabling overlapping instances) to make any instance of a typeclass automatically an instance of another too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**: don't do that, or, if you insist, use `-XOverlappingInstances`.

1. This is not what the `Show` class is there for. `Show` is for simply showing plain data, in a way that is actually Haskell code and can be used as such again, yielding the original value.
2. `SampleSpace` should perhaps not be a class in the first place. It seems to be basically the class of types that have something like `Map a Rational` associated with them. Why not just use that as a field in a plain `data` type?
3. Even if we accept the design... such a generic `Show` instance (or, indeed, generic instance for any single-parameter class) runs into problems when someone makes another instance for a concrete type – in the case of `Show`, there are of course already plenty of instances around. Then how should the compiler decide which of the two instances to use? GHC can do it, in fact: if you turn on the `-XOverlappingInstances` extension, it will select the more specific one (i.e. `instance SampleSpace s => Show (s a)` is “overridden” by any more specific instance), but really this isn't as trivial as may seem – what if somebody defined *another* such generic instance? Crucial to recall: Haskell type classes *are always open*, i.e. basically the compiler has to assume that *all* types could possibly in any class. Only when a specific instance is invoke will it actually need the proof for that, but it can never proove that a type *isn't* in some class.

What I'd recommend instead – since that `Show` instance doesn't merely show data, it should be made a different function. Either

```
showDistribution :: (SampleSpace s, Show a, Ord a) => s a -> String
```

or indeed

```
showDistribution :: (Show a, Ord a) => SampleSpace a -> String
```

where `SampleSpace` is a single concrete type, instead of a class.

Comment: Well... it doesn't strictly have to be Haskell code, although that is how it traditionally is. Off the top of my head, I know that `HList` produces something that's not Haskell code, but that is otherwise sane. The idea that it should produce Haskell code seems more restrictive than useful, because `Read` doesn't have a type checker—you always need to know the type of what you're reading, and I don't know of any way to make `Read` work with existentials.

Comment: SampleSpace is a typeclass because a side from the type you have guessed quite correctly, there's also another, representing a SampleSpace where all events are equally probable. Hence it does not need to store the probability in a data field, it just needs to return 1/n, where n is number of events in that space. Now I would like to use the two types polimorfically - that's what I need a typeclass for. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Sventimir, you could use `data SampleSpace a = SampleSpace {events :: [a], member :: a-> Bool, probability :: a -> Rational}`.